# Excel can i add Columns Manually to query and preserve row integrity -linkage- when the original table rows number changes?

Tags: excel, powerquery

Good Day
I have a table -20 columns- named (employees) with all Basic data of employees in sheet1, and in sheet2 I query 2 columns from the table (employees) and adding 3 columns with manually entered data and formulas.
when rows in the table (employees) rearranged or rows deleted the manually columns doesn't affect, can they be linked to follow changes in the main table?

thanks for the help and sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: See https://exceleratorbi.com.au/self-referencing-tables-power-query/

Comment: Thanks horseyride